# Рассчитать сумму с условиями jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, калькулятор

Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать следующее условие по расчету стоимости.

у меня есть форма html http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrvzpO

```
<form> 
<input type="text" id="text-field">
<input type="text" id="check-field">
<p id="summ"></p>
</form>
```

Если в текстовое поле с id="text-field" я ввожу число от 10 до 15, то оно умножается на 200 (выполняется одно из условий)
если я ввожу от 20 до 30, то умножается на 400 и т.д.

Если в текстовое поле с id="check-field" я ввожу число от 0 до 15, то оно умножается на 10 (первое условие)
если я ввожу от 50 до 60, то умножается на 200 и т.д.

А в поле с id summ должна считаться сумма этих полей.

Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, я думаю, что дальше сами сможете.

```js
// Подключаю слушатель к input по его id
$('#text-field').bind('input', function() {
  // Проверяю, входит ли параметр в наш интервал
  if ($(this).val() > 10 && $(this).val() < 15) {
    // Если входит, то вывожу в p произведение параметра на 200
    $("#summ").html($(this).val() * 200);
  }
  else{
       // Иначе, вывожу предупреждающий текст
       $("#summ").html("Input is not >10 and <15. Please change input number");
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text-field">
  <input type="text" id="check-field">
  <p id="summ"></p>
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### UPDATE

Отвечаю на вопрос из комментариев.

```js
// Подключаю слушатель к input по его id
$('#text-field').bind('input', function() {
  $("#summ").html(+($(this).val()) + +($("#check-field").val()));

});

// Подключаю слушатель к input по его id
$('#check-field').bind('input', function() {
  $("#summ").html(+($(this).val()) + +($("#text-field").val()));
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text-field">
  <input type="text" id="check-field">
  <p id="summ"></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, с этим разобрался. а каким образом можно сложить эти введеннные числа в id summ ? т.е. в id text-field у меня получилось число 20, например, в check-field число 15. и два эти числа должны сложиться в summ.

Comment: @Федор, обновил ответ. Если вопрос закрыт, то нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.